# Use array in codeigniter view

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, view

I am a beginner to codeIgniter and have looked for an answer to this on the CI forums and google, and even here...

OK I have searched for this and every time I find answers to this pertaining to use a `foreach()` to get the data out of the array then do something with it in the foreach loop; this is not what i wish to do.

I am building a site whereby I would like to store site information, such as site title, description, abstract, keywords etc in a database table with just one row (rather than having to go to the html and do it there..)

So far I have something like this in my model:

```
    function getAll(){
    $q = $this->db->get('system');

    if($q->num_rows() > 0){
            return $q->row();
    }
}
```

in my controller I have:

```
function index(){
    $this->load->model("system_model");
    $data[] = $this->system_model->getAll();    
    $this->load->view('home', $data);
}
```

and in my view I wish to have very simply (html tags are descriptive only):

```
   <title><?php echo $this->title; ?></title>
<description><?php echo $this->description; ?></description>
```

As you can see a foreach loop would not work in this instance and I don't believe that the best way to do this is loop through the array in the controller and then pass each individual array part into the view as a separate variable..

Is this at all possible?

EDIT

I have given the tick to the first answer as that put me on the right track to find the solution (although it might not be 100% correct its working) in order to get this to work I followed answer number 1, but then in the view I did the following:

```
<title><?php echo$system[0]->title; ?></title>
```

Comment: Sounds like an unnecessary db call. I hope you're at least planning on caching this.

Comment: i will be caching it when i've learnt how to do it, for now im just learning

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give the $data[] array a key name

```
function index(){
    $this->load->model("system_model");
    $data['mydata'] = $this->system_model->getAll();    
    $this->load->view('home', $data);
}
```

and in the view file you can echo or loop or whatever based on that key

```
echo $mydata
```

or

```
foreach($mydata as $md){
echo $md
}
```

The best way to query the database in the model is to do the following:

```
function get_user_by_id($id){
    $this->db->where('id', $id);
    $query = $this->db->get('users');
    $result = $query->result_array();
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: if you want to get al the data, remove the following: $this->db->where('id,$id);

Comment: Depends if he wants to use the object-oriented method to retrieve data or not. He seems to prefer this notation as shown in his view example. If you do OPer, use result(); as this will return an object which can also be accessed using array notation.

Comment: thanks for the reply, if i use this method and then do `code`<?php echo $system; ?>`code` i just get array and if i try $system->title; i get an error..

Comment: I don't understand where you're getting $system from or have you renamed $data to that? If you're using @tylerpennys code then you're returning the result as an array which means you need to access data like $system['title']

Comment: yes sorry, i renamed it to $system. thanks for the comment, i will test this later

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

In your controller use:

```
function index(){
    $this->load->model("system_model");
    $data = $this->system_model->getAll(); 

    $this->load->view('home', $data);
}
```

Your view will then look like this:

```
   <title><?php echo $title; ?></title>
<description><?php echo $description; ?></decription>
```

Also, with your database query (in general) use result() as it sounds like you want more than one row:

```
   function getAll(){
    $q = $this->db->get('system');

    if($q->num_rows() > 0){
            return $q->result();
    }
```

Comment: hi thanks for the reply, i still get an error using the above code.. undefined variable title..

Comment: further to this if i var_dump the $data variable i get the following:`array
  0 => 
    object(stdClass)[18]
      public 'id' => string '1' (length=1)
      public 'title' => string 'EVECTK' (length=6)
      public 'decription' => string 'EVECTK is the Corporation Tool for EVE Online Corporations. It provides unparalleled functionality; and best of all - its free!  ' (length=129)
      public 'keywords' => string 'some keywords' (length=54)  ' (length=128)
`

Comment: In your original code you are using "$data[] =" you need to just use "$data =" in your controller as you are adding an extra level to the array for no reason. Use this along with my other edits and it should work fine :)